# R Lattice - issues with log10 scaling of a stacked bar plot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm attempting to prepare a stack bar plot using R lattice with the data plotted using log10 scale on the vertical axis. Without the log10 scale things are as expected

```
# Dummy data
Grp <- c('A','B','A','B','A','B')
Sub <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
tst <- rbind(Grp,Sub)
tst <- data.frame(t(tst),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tst$Val <- c(5,10,10,20,80,90) 

# Stacked bar chart normal scale
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)

barchart(Val ~ Grp, 
         data = tst, 
         horiz = FALSE,
         main = '',
         groups = Sub,
         stack = TRUE,
         auto.key=list(space = 'top', columns = 3, 
                   points = FALSE, rectangles = TRUE,
                   title = ''),
         par.strip.text = list(col = 'white', font = 1.5),
         panel = function(x,y,...){
           panel.grid(h = -1, v = 0);
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
         }
)
```

[image: Stacked Bar - normal scale]
Inspection of the chart above shows a maximum value of A at 95 and for B at 120.

However when I plot using log 10 scale as below

```
barchart(Val ~ Grp, 
         data = tst, 
         horiz = FALSE,
         main = '',
         groups = Sub,
         stack = TRUE,
         scales = list(y = list(log = 10)),
         yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks,
         auto.key=list(space = 'top', columns = 3, 
                   points = FALSE, rectangles = TRUE,
                   title = ''),
         par.strip.text = list(col = 'white', font = 1.5),
         panel = function(x,y,...){
            panel.grid(h = -1, v = 0);
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
        }
```

)

[image]

The proportions of the stacked bars seems to be about right for log10 scale by the y scale is incorrect? I'm not understanding something here

Comment: Don't log-transform a stacked barplot. It conceptionally can't work (log(0) is undefined) and, even if you disregard that and somehow make it work, you get something difficult to interpret (the visual ratios between the different parts of the bar would be a distorted representation of the actual ratios). I'm not surprised that lattice is not able to do this.

Comment: Roland thanks for your edits and comments.  The reason for the log10 scaling as I wish to visually compare the range of  results for each group in the stacked bars and visually compare these values across groups - the first values  (group 1) are of importance but get lost when the group 3 values are large (these can range up to 1000). Suggestions as to how better present this type of data welcome

Comment: Well, you can't achieve that with stacked bars on a log-scale. Simply don't stack the bars, then you can use a log-scale if you say bars start, e.g., at 1. But I would use a scatter plot or something like that with a log-scale.